# Sentry integration with React/Node app - no issues for current release

Tags: javascript, webpack, sentry

This is first time I'm trying to integrate Sentry into my project:

This is what I added into `plugins`:

```
import SentryPlugin from 'webpack-sentry-plugin';
new SentryPlugin({
      organization: 'my-org',
      project: 'my-project',
      apiKey: 'myAPIKey',
      release: provess.env.GIT_COMMIT_HASH,
    });
```

In the build I can see that the sourcemaps are generated, and they have the same name as regular JS files, but just with `.map` added.

I have also configured the `Raven`:

```
import Raven from 'raven-js';
const initializeRaven = () => {
    const configuration = { /* some ignoreUrls and ignoreErrors options from https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/tips/ */ };
    const commitHash = process.env.GIT_COMMIT_HASH;
    if (commitHash) configuration.release = commitHash;
    const sentryDSN = 'my-sentry-dsn';
    try {
        Raven
            .config(sentryDSN, configuration)
            .install();
        console.log('Integrated Sentry...', Raven);
     } catch (e) {
         console.error('Failed to integrate Sentry');
     }
};
```

And now when logged into `sentry.io` I can see in my releases the latest release. But when looking into the issues of the release there are none. And the latest issues that appears have the release set to `n/a`.

When I expect an error (like `componentDidCatch`) I just use:

```
const extra = { method: 'request-method', url: 'request-url' };
Raven.captureMessage(error.message, { level: 'error', extra });
```

What am I missing?